# UART and DMA data size

Tags: uart, rs485

I want to work with the RS485 interface with UART protocole, but I need to choose which method useful for me.

I want to use DMA but the data length is not constant, how can I manage the DMA with non constant data buffer size ?

or which method useful ?

Answer (score 5):

It makes sense to distinguish between transmission and reception of data as they are quite different in this context.

Transmission is straightforward. If several bytes are ready to be transmitted, DMA can be configured for this specific length and the transmission can be started.

It is usually helpful to add a buffer. So if the code wants to transmit additional data while DMA/UART are still transmitting, the data is added to the buffer. When the DMA completes, the buffer is checked and if it is not empty, the next transmission is immediately started. Without the buffer, the code would need to wait until the DMA transfer completes, which partially defeats the purpose of the DMA.

Reception of variable length data is more complex. The main question usually is: How do you know you have received sufficient bytes to be able to process a chunk of data.

A common pattern is that the received data contains a delimiter separating messages, e.g. a newline character separating lines and each line is message to be processed. In such a case, I would set up DMA with a circular buffer. DMA is set up once and doesn't trigger any interrupts. Instead, the code regularly checks the circular buffer to see if data has arrived and if it contains a new line character. If so, the line is processed. The circular buffer also helps with buffering if processing takes some time; DMA simply continues to write data to the buffer.

Another pattern is that the message contains the message length at a fixed position in the message header. In this case, DMA can be setup with a specific length. First it is configured for the length of the message header, then the message length is decoded and DMA is setup for the remaining length of the message. After that, it starts over with the header length. Configuring DMA must be quick and happen in an interrupt. Buffering is still possible but somewhat trickier.

Comment: Several embedded UARTs can also be configured for a delimiter interrupt that triggers when a specific character is received, and several DMA controllers can also interrupt if the receive buffer is not empty and a timeout has been reached.

Comment: I waited to think about it. When I receive the data with DMA, for example with HAL_UART_Receive_DMA function, and I give a buffer and fix max buffer size to catch the data. Can I detect how many bytes the DMA takes and reset this counter at any point?

Comment: It's possible to read how many bytes DMA has already processed (or received in your case). I'm not sure if there is a HAL function for it. But there is certainly a DMA register for it. The proper way to reset it is to stop the DMA and then restart it. If you use a circular buffer, there's no need to reset it.

Comment: Thank you for your long explanation, it helps to understand. But I need to know where is the end character in my buffer, because I get end character I need the set to RS485 device to transmit mode. So when I use common pattern method as you say, how can I start DMA receive data, if I use the REceive DMA function I need to buffer length, If receive data not enough the fill the buffer what happened how can I catch ?

Answer (score 0):

The buffer size is constant, can't be variable, you define it in the declaration. The received  or transmitted data length is not constant, meaning the buffer is several times larger than largest data packet. Depends on your architecture, maybe you can trigger an interrupt if new data don't arrive within few clock cycles. Assuming the transmitting device sends data packets in bursts, then there is certain mechanism to trigger a timeout interrupt with on-delay timer or counter that counts clock ticks for specified baudrate.