# Determining how many bytes DMA receives with HAL_UART_Receive_DMA

Tags: stm32, uart, interrupts, dma

How can I determine how many bytes to receive with DMA?
I use the this function:
`HAL_UART_Receive_DMA(&huart2, (uint8_t*)rs485RxDMABuffer, 100)`

If I don't receive 100 bytes, the `USART2_IRQHandler` and `DMA1_Stream5_IRQHandler` interrupts never trigger, so I can't count or catch anything.

I need to know how many data to receive and which data to receive, because I receive a non-constant amount of data. I want to capture exactly where the DMA is in the buffer. How can I do that ?

When the sender sends 10 bytes of data I need to catch that.

Comment: I have proposed several ways how to deal with DMA and variable length data as an [answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/570998/142001) to your previous question. In a comment, additional ways have been proposed. Don't they work for you? Or why are you trying to go with an approach that will hardly be successful? And can you describe what kind of data you receive and how you detect that a sufficient chunks for further processing has been received? Does it include a message delimiter? Or a pause?

Comment: Yes, it's help. But this is exactly where I got stuck.So that I can receive with DMA, I need to use HAL_UART_Receive_DMA function. But the problem starting here, I have to give a constat buffer size like 100 byte, if I couldnt receive number of 100 bytes on the data line, where can I find end character which interrupt or callback know, where is the end of my data? 
I'm confused about this because when I find the end character I need to put the RS485 line in transmit mode

Comment: Take a step back and forget about `HAL_UART_Receive_DMA` for the moment. Instead describe what condition should trigger the processing of the received data. Is it a message delimiter? Is it a timeout? Is it a length field in the data? Or can you process any chunk of data?

Comment: So you can't ask the DMA controller about how much it has transferred or is left to transfer so you could see that something has been transferred?

Comment: @Codo I have specific frame and this frame's second and third byte include information about the data frame length. And Transmitter send me to this message when you want and message lentgh is not constant. And data have, 2 byte specific end of the bytes.The only condition that I have, to trigger the Receive, is listening to the uart line.

Comment: The easiest approach is likely to first call `HAL_UART_Receive_DMA` with 3 bytes as the length. In the interrupt handler or callback, decode the frame length. At this point, the length is know. So call `HAL_UART_Receive_DMA` again with `frame_length - 3` as the length. In the second call of the interrupt handler / callback, you now have a complete frame, which you can processes. Additionally, call `HAL_UART_Receive_DMA` again for 3 bytes to be ready for the next frame.

Comment: First, read this: https://github.com/akospasztor/stm32-dma-uart and accompanying literature in the references. Then you will get a vague idea what you can do with DMA receive. I have told you in previous question: hardware counter timeout or timer timeout.

Comment: @Codo At the point it enters in the ISR and decodes the header, the data stream is already lost.

Comment: Yet better description: https://github.com/MaJerle/stm32-usart-uart-dma-rx-tx

Comment: @MarkoBuršič Whether data is lost, depends on the transmission speed. But I agree: a circular buffer is more robust if done properly. The linked GitHub doesn't seem to have a solution at first sight. If the messages can have varying length incl. be very small, they might never trigger the half full interrupt. So a timer would be needed to regularly check for messages.

Comment: @Codo In a high speed RS485 that uses some deterministic protocol, for example Profibus then AN3109 method 1 is suitable, with exact gap of Nr of bits - it requires HW counter tied together on RX pin. The Modbus protocol could use method 2 timeout.  Other methods, using interrupt on size of the FIFO - full/half are of little use for RS485.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I've question about the circular buffer, if I use circular buffer when I configured HAL_UART_Receive_DMA to 100 byte, but I only receive 5 byte, all 100 byte buffer fill with the these 5 byte for example AA BB CC DD EE AA BB CC DD .., when the buffer fill how can I do that, stop the dma end flush the buffer or, check BUSY flag and flush the buffer ?

Answer (score 3):

`huart2.hdmarx->Instance->CNDTR(or NDTR)` is the number of bytes left to be received. In your case this is set to 100 when you call `HAL_UART_Receive_DMA(..., 100);`. When 10 bytes are received, this number is decremented by 10; so the number of bytes received is `100 - CNDTR`.

However you have to check this register manually probably in the main while loop or in a timer isr. If you want to know when UART stops receiving data, check [this](https://programming.vip/docs/stm32-hal-library-learning-serial-idle-interrupt.html). If you need an interrupt every time **one** byte is received then you should probably receive only one byte using dma and in the callback call `HAL_UART_Receive_DMA(..., 1)` again.

---

##### Update:

You can also use `HAL_UARTEx_ReceiveToIdle_DMA()` which calls `HAL_UARTEx_RxEventCallback(UART_HandleTypeDef * huart, uint16_t Size)` which gives you the number of bytes received (`Size`). However it gets called on idle, transfer complete **and transfer half complete** and you can't know which one has happened so you have to manually disable half transfer interrupt.

Here's an example:

```
uint8_t buffer[100];

void HAL_UARTEx_RxEventCallback(UART_HandleTypeDef* huart, uint16_t Size)
{
    printf("UART received: %hu byte(s)\n", Size);
    printf("%.*s\n\n", Size, buffer);

    HAL_UARTEx_ReceiveToIdle_DMA(huart, buffer, 100);

    //disable half transfer interrupt; it is enabled in HAL_UARTEx_ReceiveToIdle_DMA()
    __HAL_DMA_DISABLE_IT(huart1.hdmarx, DMA_IT_HT);
}

int main()
{
    HAL_UARTEx_ReceiveToIdle_DMA(&huart1, buffer, 100);

    //disable half transfer interrupt; it is enabled in HAL_UARTEx_ReceiveToIdle_DMA()
    __HAL_DMA_DISABLE_IT(huart1.hdmarx, DMA_IT_HT);
}
```

Needless to say, you should add a DMA request for RX in STM32CubeMX and enable its interrupt.

Answer (score 0):

DMA has a register for **N**umber of **D**ata to **T**ransfer (**R**egister), that you set to 100. The one SMMB is referring to as C**NDTR**. You can find its name in the reference manual.

When a transfer happens, the number is decreased by 1. DMA will only trigger interrupt when it's finished with all transfers (NDTR becomes 0). (Transfer Complete interrupt; there is also optional Half-Transfer complete).

I think a solution would be: set an interrupt for UART RXNE (byte received) when initializing UART DMA reception, after first byte received and RXNE interrupt is triggered, in the RXNE ISR disable RXNE interrupt so further bytes don't trigger it again, but enable IDLE interrupt, which won't fire immediately because the transmission is already happening, but it will detect the end of the transmission (so if the whole message was 1 byte, it should trigger right after RXNE handler ISR; technically they share an interrupt and ISR of course, I mean their handlers). There you can check the number in NDTR and disable IDLE interrupt so it doesn't fire all the time after the transmission ends.